# How to make a element follow another element when dragging with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, draggable

I need make a element follow another element when dragging, but with delay in the animation, is similar to "Chat heads of facebook's messenger", you know, the bubbles on Android.

This is my jQuery plugin:

```
// Draggable plugin
(function($) {
$.fn.drag = function(options) {
    options = $.extend({
        handle: null,
        cursor: 'move',
        draggingClass: 'dragging',
        heads: null
    }, options);

    var $handle = this,
        $drag = this;

    if( options.handle ) {
        $handle = $(options.handle);
    }

    $handle
        .css('cursor', options.cursor)
        .on("mousedown", function(e) {
            var x = $drag.offset().left - e.pageX,
                y = $drag.offset().top - e.pageY,
                z = $drag.css('z-index');

            $drag.css('z-index', 100000);

            $(document.documentElement)
                .on('mousemove.drag', function(e) {
                    var chats = $($(options.heads).get().reverse());

                    chats.each(function(i) {
                        $(chats[i]).css({ left: $drag.position().left - (10*i)});
                        $(chats[i]).css({top: $drag.position().top});
                    });

                    $drag.offset({
                        left: x + e.pageX,
                        top: y + e.pageY
                    });
                })
                .one('mouseup', function() {
                    $(this).off('mousemove.drag');
                    $drag.css('z-index', z);

                    var window_width = $(window).width();
                    var window_height = $(window).height();
                    var head_wpostion = $(options.heads).position().left;
                    var head_hposition = $(options.heads).position().top;

                    if( head_wpostion > (window_width / 2) )
                    {
                      $(options.heads).animate({left: (window_width-40)+"px"}, 300 );
                      $(options.heads).animate({left: (window_width-50)+"px"}, 300 );
                    }
                    else
                    {
                      $(options.heads).animate({left: "-15px"}, 300 );
                      $(options.heads).animate({left: "-5px"}, 300 );
                    }

                    if( head_hposition > (window_height - 50) )
                    {
                      $(options.heads).animate({top: (window_height-75)+"px"}, 200 );
                      $(options.heads).animate({top: (window_height-65)+"px"}, 200 );
                    }

                    if( head_hposition < 0 )
                    {
                      $(options.heads).animate({top: "15px"}, 150 );
                      $(options.heads).animate({top: "5px"}, 150 );
                    }
                });

            // disable selection
            e.preventDefault();
        });
};
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

the only way you can do that is if you position the element you want to to be dragged along relevant to the drag-able element.